# How do I replace a draw.rect (Square) with an image of my choice to use as my main player character?

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently using just a square as my character. Just looking to get some help/advice on how I can use a .png to use as my character, rather than a drawn shape??

```
class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = Surface((32,32))
        self.image.fill(Color("#0000FF"))
        self.image.convert()
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change to:

```
self.image = pygame.image.load("yourImagePath").convert()
```

If you want to use transparency call `convert_alpha()` instead of `convert()`.